# fullCalendar User events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm stacked. I have basic fullCalendar for User model.  I want to add 2 buttons, where User can separate calendar into two. In first he get only his events and in seconds he get all events of all users. How should i do this? im new at rails :)
this is my js code

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar(

    events: '/events.json'
    eventColor: '#378006'
    eventBackgroundColor: 'red'

  )
```

and my json event file

```
json.array!(@events) do |event|

  json.extract! event, :id, :title, :description, :user_id
  json.start event.start_time
  json.end event.end_time

  json.url event_url(event, format: :html)
  if (event.user_id == current_user.id)
    json.color 'green'
  end

  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this you can do like this:

**1**)Add two buttons on your view named as "User Events" and "All Users Events".

**2**)Now set a global variable in your js named as calEvents.

**3**)Now use button click event that means set the value of calEvents equal to current_user event when user click on "User Events" button and if user click on "All User events" then change the value of calEvents equal to all user events.

Note: Make sure your events should be in formate of json.

To achieve this you can code like:

```
calEvents = ''

$(document).on 'click', 'all_user_events', ->
  calEvents = '/events.json'
  return

$(document).on 'click', 'user_events', ->
  calEvents = '/events/user_events.json'
  return

$(document).ready ->
  calEvents = '/events.json'
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar(

    events: calEvents
    eventColor: '#378006'
    eventBackgroundColor: 'red'

)
```

In your **events_controller** add new action

```
def user_events
  @events = current_user.events
  render json: @events
end
```

In your **config/routs.rb** file

```
get 'events/user_events' => 'events#user_events'
```

**EDIT:**

if you want to do this via checkbox you can do like this:

```
$(document).on 'change', 'your_checkobx_id_to_select_user_events ', ->
  if @checked
    calEvents = 'events/user_events.json'
    return

$(document).on 'change', 'your_checkobx_id_to_select_all_events', ->
  if @checked
    calEvents = 'events.json'
    return
```

Hope I have understood your problem in a correct way and this will help you.

Comment: Can it possible to do it without buttons? i want to do it with checkbox

Comment: Yes, you can do it with check box too

Comment: Can you help with it, please :) guess it isnt hard